# related product display as mindmap view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I have the following requirement in the project.I need to have a feature to show the related products for a product.The view of the related products should be like mind map view.When a user clicks on a product i need to show the other related products expanded like a mindmap view.[image]

So the related products will expand or collapse when clicked on the parent product.Is it possible to accomplish this using javascript/jquery.

I am using asp.net mvc 3 for development purpose.

Also we should design this without a requirement for plugin like flash or Silverlight, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Javascript mind map implementations, several of them ports of [Kenneth Kufluk's version](http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/).  You could probably expand these into what you are looking for.